# Add objects of a class and store in a static field of another class and access them through properties of the second class

Tags: c#

I want to store objects of a non-static class in static fields of another non-static class and access them through the properties of the second class. Please, help me.

```
class Student
{
    private string fullname;
    private string course;
    private string subject;
    public Student(string fullname, string course)
    {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.course = course;            
    }

    public Student(string fullname, string course, string subject)
    {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.course = course;
        this.subject = subject;            
    }

    public string FullName { get { return fullname; } set { fullname = value; }}        
        public string Course { get { return course; } set { course = value; }}
        public string Subject { get { return subject; } set { subject = value;}}
}
```

```
class StudentData
{
    private static Student bscStudent;
    private static Student mscStudent;        

    public StudentData()
    {
    }

    private static void GetStudentData()
    {
        Student student = new Student(" Isoboye Vincent", "IT");
        Student student2 = new Student(" Doris Atuzie", "IT", "C#");            

        bscStudent= student;
        mscStudent= student2;                       
    }

    public static Student BscStudent { get { return bscStudent; } set { bscStudent = value; } }
    public static Student MscStudent { get { return mscStudent; } set { mscStudent = value; } }        
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List of students");
        Console.WriteLine(StudentData.BscStudent);
        Console.WriteLine(StudentData.MscStudent);            

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

```
// Output: 
//List of students

-
```

Comment: We know what you want, now what is going wrong?

Comment: The output is just "List of students" and nothing else.

Comment: FYI/Nitpicking: "_objects of a non-static class_" objects are always instances from non-static classes, since it is not possible to create object instances from static classes (that's what it means to be a "static class"). Secondly: "_static fields of another non-static class_" With regard to the nature of a static field it it is irrelevant whether it is declared in a static or non-static class. It will always be just the same kind of static field... ;-)

Comment: Indent **all** your code four spaces so that it renders correctly.

Comment: You never set the property, so the property is unset. The best practice is to write to a property *before* you read it.  You've got a blank piece of paper and you're asking us why it is blank; you're the one who didn't write anything on it!

Comment: The property setters are called in `GetStudentData`, which you never invoke. If you want that method invoked, you're going to have to write some code which invokes it.

Comment: I have tried it but not working. I put the objects in the static field of the second class in the setter method of the property. Yet, not working. Please, show that line of code.

Comment: If you put the line of GetStudentData(); as the first line of Main, is that changing things for the better?

Comment: It works that way. But, the task is to access it from the StudentData class through a static property.

Comment: @Isobar now I understand the problem and subsequently I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand the problem, so I propose this solution:

```
private static Student _BscStudent = null;
public static Student BscStudent { 
    get {
        if (_BscStudent == null) {
            _BscStudent = new Student(" Isoboye Vincent", "IT");
        } 
        return _BscStudent; 
    } 
    set { _BscStudent = value; } 
}

private static Student _MscStudent = null;
public static Student MscStudent { 
    get { 
        if (_MscStudent == null) {
            _MscStudent = new Student(" Doris Atuzie", "IT", "C#");
        } 
        return _MscStudent; 
    } 
    set { 
        _MscStudent = value; 
    } 
}
```

I did not work with C# for a very long time, so I might not remember an easier way. Anyway, start with this solution and maybe later if you find out a better way, then refactor this code.

Comment: Bro thanks for your effort but it still not working only showing a blank output.

Comment: @Isobar can you edit your question and add your current code? Maybe a detail is missing.